# Replacing files in svn tree with an external reference results in delete/checkout conflict

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I replaced files that originally existed in SVN repository with `svn:externals` references.  Now every `svn update` deletes each file and checks it back out.

How do I fix this?

### Details

With all code revision-controlled under SVN I started with:

```
proj_a/trunk
  +---- module_a
    +----- file_a
    +----- file_b
```

Than decided to make `module_a` a library item, so moved it to a different location in the SVN repository with the intention to than reference it with `svn:externals`.  The desired result was:

```
lib_a/trunk
  +---- module_a
    +----- file_a
    +----- file_b

proj_a/trunk
  +---- module_a  [svn:externals to file_a and file_b]
```

svn commands used:

```
svn remove module_a/file_a module_a/file_b
svn commit
svn pedit svn:externals module_a
svn commit
```

This seemed to work and upon `svn update` **file_a** and **file_b** were checked out.  However, every time I run `svn update` **file_a** and **file_b** get deleted and re-checked out as externals.

Furthermore, running `svn up --ignore-externals` results in **file_a** and **file_b** being deleted.

I have unsuccessfully looked for other questions that may suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `svn propset` to set your external repository?

Comment: Thanks for your attempt at an answer.  AFAIK `svn propset` has same end effect as `svn pedit` - it manipulates the property value - only difference being that `svn propset` will create or replace entire property with provided value (and it's hard to do multi-line entries), while `svn propedit` uses an editor to _edit_ the value.  I am not aware of any other difference that may help resolve the issue.